# Why does this code to fill an Array create a memory leak?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, memory-leaks

I have encountered a somewhat baffling problem with the simple task of filling an Array dynamically in Java. The following is a snapshot from where the problem originates:

```
entries = new Object[ (n = _entries.length + 1) ] ;

for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {

            entry = ( i == (n - 1) )  ?  addition  :  _entries[i]  ;

            entries[i] = entry ;

            //...

}
```

Where `_entries` is a source `Array` (field of the class); `entries` is initialized as an `Array` of `Object`s

```
Object[] entries = null ;
```

and `addition` is the `Object` to be added (passed as an Argument to the method this code is in).

---

The code passes the compiler but results in a memory-leak when called. I was able to narrow down the cause to the line where the code attempts to fill the new `Array`

```
 entries[i] = entry ;
```

however, I cannot think of any reason why this would cause a memory-leak. I'm guessing the root of the issue must be either an extremely stupid fault on my part or an extremely arcane problem with Java. :-)

If you need more background let me know.

**Edit:**

Tomcat's log tells me:

> A web application appears to have started a thread named ... but has failed to stop it. 
>   This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Other than that obviously the page loading the class does not finish loading or loads very slowly.

**Edit:**

The problem might be somewhere else (at a more expected location) after all. Apparently Tomcat wasn't loading the class files all the time when I tried to pin down the faulty code and this mislead me a bit. I now suspect a infinte for-each loop caused by a defective Iterator implementation up in the call stack to be at fault. 
In any case, thanks for your input! Always much appreciated!

---

I will use a `Collection` (probably a `Vector`) instead of an `Array` as a work-around; still, I'd like to know what the problem here is.

TIA,

FK82

Comment: Off topic: what does $entries mean? I have never seen $ notation used in this context in java. Can someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: @shadow: That puzzles me too. I guess this is some kind of code templating mechanism.

Comment: What makes you think there's a memory leak? That's hard to do in Java.

Comment: A baffling question.  On an unhelpful note, why not just use System.arrayCopy()?

Comment: @ shadowfoxmi: that's a personal quirk of mine. I "flag" class variables with a "$" sign. Just a matter of code lay-out. The "$" does not have a special meaning in Java afaik.

Comment: @Allison: I'm adding an entry to the source Array.

Comment: @ Gabe: The class is used in a web application run on an Apache-Server. The memory-leak is protocolled in the logs.

Comment: How were you able to trace this "leak" so precisely (up to one line)? And yes, as someone comments above: why do you think it *is* a memory leak?

Comment: It probably isn't relevant, but the language guidelines specifically recommend against using dollar signs in your variable names.

Comment: @FX82: it does not have syntactic meaning, but by convention it is only used in auto-generated code. Most other developers will find this quirk rather irritating.

Comment: @Gabe: Having memory leaks is actually quite easy in Java.

Comment: @ Sergey Mikhanov: I carved out pieces of code using comments and checked if the problem persisted. This is the line that when uncommented resulted in a memory leak.

Comment: @ Michael Borgwardt, yock: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: I'll try removing the "$" sign on the variable names and report back.

Comment: How did you quantify it as a memory leak?

Comment: @yock: I'm guessing you mean "quantify". Whatever the case, the Tomcat log reports unclosed additional threads telling you they are likely to cause memory leaks.

Comment: There's nothing in your code snippet creating new Threads.

Comment: The language spec says $ should be used in internal and generated identifiers. An inner class B in a class A is compiled to a class A$B. Btw, all unicode currency chars are legal constituents of Java identifiers.

Comment: @jmg Legal, not suggested: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html "Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this practice is discouraged"

Comment: How, did you arrive at the conclusions: (1) There is a memory leak. (2) It is caused by this line.

Comment: @yock: You're right, but is encouraged to use it code generators, byte code rewriting engines, etc. in order to avoid name clashed with hand-written code. That's why it is discouraged to be used in hand written code.

Comment: @jmg: read the comments above.

Comment: @yock: Indeed there is nothing. That's why I'm asking this question. I don't get that myself.

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak? How did you narrow it down to that line? Where are your variables declared?

Comment: @ biziclop: read the comments please.

Comment: @FK82 The problem is that somewhere you're starting a thread, perhaps implicittly by using an Executor or some form of timer, or even using a JDBC driver. The log from Tomcat does not have anything to do with the posted code though.

Comment: @ nos: a webapplication is a thread run by Tomcat afaik. Tomcat might try to run another thread for a copy of the webapplication that uses this code once it failed (indefinitely if there is no stop condition). At least that is my  guess why there is a memory leak in the first place.

Comment: Can you post the full message for that error from Tomcat, please?

Comment: @FK82 If the code goes into an infinte loop or does a blocking call that it never gets out of, then yes it could be. The code posted does not go into an infinite loop or do anything other bad though - that is assuming the code does not access some global variables, or instance variables of a Servlet - it might have multi threading issues if it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see a memory leak, but your code is more complicated than it needs to be. How about this:

```
newLength = $entries.length + 1;
entries = new Object[ newLength ] ;

for(i = 0 ; i < newLength - 1 ; i++) {
        entries[i] = $entries[i];
        //...
}

entries[ newLength - 1 ] = addition;
```

No need to check if you are at the last entry all the time and you could use a array copy method as suggested by Alison.

Think of this post as a comment. I just posted it as an answer because I don't know how code is formatted in comments...

Comment: Yeah, there is some subsequent code (a conditional break) that I left out which makes it practical to write it the way I did.

Answer (score 3):

So, about your Tomcat log message:

> A web application appears to have started a thread named ... but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

This says that your servlet or something similar started a new thread, and this thread is still running when your servlet finished its operation. It doesn't relate at all to your example code (if this code isn't the one starting the thread).

Superfluous threads, even more when each HTTP-request starts a new one (which does not finish soon) can create a memory leak, since each thread needs quite some space for its stack, and also may inhibit garbage-collection by referencing objects who are not needed anymore. Make sure that your thread is really needed, and think about using a threadpool instead (preferably container-managed, if this is possible).

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me,

please find the sample code. and change it to accordingly

```
class test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {


   String[] str = new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6"};

   int n=0;
   Object[] entries = new Object[ (n = 5 + 1) ] ;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {

            Object entry = ( i == (n - 1) )  ?  new Object()  :  str [i]  ;

            entries[i] = entry ;



    }
   System.out.println(entries[3]);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps by Memory Leak you are meaning an OutOfMemoryException? Sometime you get that in Java if you do not have the minimum heap size set high enough (and also a well defined max heap size too) when you start up. If there is not enough heap created at startup then you can sometimes use it up faster than the JVM has time to allocate more memory to the heap or to garbage collect. Unfortunately, there is no "right answer" here. You just have to play with different settings to get the right result (ie, known as "tuning the JVM"). In other words, this is more of an art than a science.

And in case you didn't know, you pass the arguments to the JVM on the command line when firing up your program -Xmin 250m -Xmax 1024m is an example. You must specify the values in megabytes. The first sets the minimum heap (at startup) to 250 megabytes. The second argument sets the max heap size at one gigabyte.

Just another thought to go by as I too am puzzled by how you could trace a memory leak to one line of code.

Comment: I do not. Again I removed code until the problem occured, which is how i figured it out.